# Mysql trigger is throwing syntax errors on my trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

When executed the trigger throws the error below . Please help

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE  TRIGGER `Problem_created` AFTER UPDATE  ON `WorkOrder_Fields` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE problem_time_stamp   int;


IF   NEW.UDF_CHAR37 ='Problem'  AND  OLD.UDF_CHAR37='Incident'

    THEN

        SET problem_time_stamp    = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())*1000);

        update workorder_fields set UDF_DATE6=problem_time_stamp    where WORKORDERID=OLD.WORKORDERID ;

    END IF;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

========================================================================

```
[root@vmesx42s32 bin]#  mysql -u root -S../tmp/mysql.sock supportcenter
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 263 to server version: 4.1.18-pro

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> DELIMITER |
mysql> CREATE  TRIGGER `Problem_created` AFTER UPDATE  ON `WorkOrder_Fields` FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> DECLARE problem_time_stamp   int;
    ->
->
    -> IF   NEW.UDF_CHAR37 ='Problem'  AND  OLD.UDF_CHAR37='Incident'

IF   NEW.UDF_CHAR37 ='Problem'  AND  OLD.UDF_CHAR37='Incident'
    ->
 -> THEN
    ->
     ->  SET problem_time_stamp    = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())*1000);
 ->

        -> update workorder_fields set UDF_DATE6=problem_time_stamp    where WORKORDERID=OLD.WORKORDERID ;
 ->
    -> END IF;
 -> END |
**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near     'TRIGGER `Problem_created` AFTER UPDATE  ON `WorkOrder_Fields` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN' at line 1**
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help Gordon .

Comment: I just modified the trigger as suggested . Moreover i want the trigger modify only those rows who have changed from incident to problem.

Comment: Trigger was modified as suggested . But still -- ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use   near 'TRIGGER `Problem_created` AFTER UPDATE  ON `WorkOrder_Fields` FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN' at line 1

Comment: Am i missing any packages in mysql installation ?

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to do an update on the table being modified by the trigger.  Instead do a `before insert` trigger and:

```
IF   NEW.UDF_CHAR37 ='Problem'  AND  OLD.UDF_CHAR37='Incident'
THEN
    SET new.UDF_DATE6 := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())*1000);  
END IF;
```

This assumes that `WORKORDERID` is not being updated, but based on its name, that seems unlikely.